# Error while importing PyQGIS plugin from ZIP on Ubuntu and MacOS: KeyError: 'use_stable_version'

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I have encountered an error while trying to import a pyQGIS plugin that I developed on Ubuntu and MacOS that didn't affect on Windows. The error follows like this:

```
An error occurred during execution of following code:
pyplugin_installer.instance().installFromZipFile(r'/home/usr/Documents/probaPyQGIS/CSVtoCSR.zip')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/pyplugin_installer/installer.py", line 650, in installFromZipFile
    self.processDependencies(pluginName)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/pyplugin_installer/installer.py", line 682, in processDependencies
    dlg = QgsPluginDependenciesDialog(plugin_id, to_install, to_upgrade, not_found)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/pyplugin_installer/qgsplugindependenciesdialog.py", line 92, in __init__
    _make_row(data, i, name)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/pyplugin_installer/qgsplugindependenciesdialog.py", line 63, in _make_row
    widget.use_stable_version = data['use_stable_version']
KeyError: 'use_stable_version'


Python version:
3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0]

QGIS version:
3.22.4-Białowieża 'Białowieża', exported
```

And my metadata.txt file looks like the following without the brackets on hastags that I just added to avoid headers:

```
[general]
(#) Mandatory items
name=CSV to CSR converter
qgisMinimumVersion=3.0.0
description= Little description here
version=1.0
author=Marc      
email=somemail@somemail.com
about=blablablaitsabout
tracker=http://bugs
repository=http://repo
plugin_dependencies=PointsToPaths==v2.0, AppendFeaturesToLayer==v1.5.0
(#) End of mandatory metadata

(#) Recommended items
qgisMaximumVersion=3.99
hasProcessingProvider=no
tags=python
homepage=http://some.url
category=Plugins
icon=icon.png
experimental=False
deprecated=False
```

What can I do?